# Custom signature algorithm in openssl certificate

Tags: openssl

Using OpenSSL, I can create and sign a certificate using the `X509` structure as such:

```
X509 *x509 = X509_new();
...
X509_set_pubkey(x509, pkey);
X509_sign(x509, pkey, EVP_sha1());
```

However, the `X509_sign` function takes an `EVP_PKEY` as the second argument, which is a wrapper for one of `RSA`, `DSA`, `DH`, or `EC_KEY`.  However, I want to sign the certificate with a custom signature scheme not supported by OpenSSL.  Is there any way I can do this?

Additionally, I need to add custom "Issuer Public Key Info" to the certificate as well to identify the certificate authority.

As a workaround, I could just sign the certificate using a dummy key, and once the SSL connection has started, provide the issuer's public key and signature of the certificate and verify it then.  Would this perhaps be a better option?

Comment: I don't recommend to use any home-made crypto instead of commonly used and proven algorithms. It will usually fail badly.

Comment: I'm actually using DJB's ed25519, so its not homemade, just not supported by OpenSSL.

Comment: I think it might be not that simple to just use another algorithm. There are several ways to sign and in X.509 everything must be standardized so you need some kind of ID for the algorithm too, see the thread http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/tls/current/msg10074.html